# Angular 4 and PHP:

Tags: php, angular, http, post

I've got a problem I can't seem to solve. I want to return my given input with a PHP file. This gives me the following error:

"
↵**Notice**:
**Trying to get property of non-object in** 
**C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php** on line **SOMEWHERE**
↵null"

This is the code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

cityName = 'From an Input field';

searchCity() {
    this.http.post(
        'http://localhost/directory/map/script.php', this.cityName)
        .subscribe((data) => {

                console.log('This is wat I get returned: ', data);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log('Errorrror:::  ', error);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And of course my php file:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$cityName = $data->cityName;

echo json_encode($cityName);
?>
```

The function searchCity() gets triggered with a button.

Comment: Dump $data and see what I'd actually there, you will be able to see the result in the response tab of dev-tools as part of the Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Doug, this is what I get with var_dump:  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["cityName"]=>
  string(9) "Amsterdam"
}

Comment: Solved it. The posting en recieving works with this code, i've deactivated: $cityName = $data->cityName; and changed echo json_encode($cityName); to echo json_encode($data); in the PHP file!

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line:

```
$cityName = $data->cityName;
```

With this

```
$cityName = isset($data->cityName) ? $data->cityName : "";
```